# PIC16F877A interfacing GPS with and without interrupt code not working

Tags: c, interrupt, pic, mplab

Hi!

I am new to PIC development and trying to interface PIC16F877A microcontroller with NEO6M GPS module. Software tools using MPLAB IDE V5.30.

The project is to display GPS time in the 4 digits 7 segment display screen.
The same code was working fine 2 days ago. Suddenly, it is just stopped working.
Please have a look at the code and let me know if the code has any problem or anything I should know. I truly appreciate your help. The code is bellow.

```
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF         // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000 //Crystal Frequency, used in delay

#include <xc.h>

#define DATA_595 PORTBbits.RB0
#define STROBE_595 PORTBbits.RB1
#define CLK_595 PORTBbits.RB2
#define LED PORTBbits.RB3
int dataArray[11];
unsigned int gtime[6];
int z = 0;

void system_init(void);

void gpsParse();
void gpser(char data);
int isEqualString(char c1[],char c2[]);
void shiftOut(unsigned int myDataOut) {

    int i = 0;
    int pinState;
    CLK_595 = 0;
    DATA_595 = 0;
    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        CLK_595 = 0;

        if (myDataOut & (1 << i)) {
            pinState = 1;
        } else {
            pinState = 0;
        }
        DATA_595 = pinState;
        CLK_595 = 1;
        DATA_595 = 0;
    }
    CLK_595 = 0;
}

void printDisplay(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    STROBE_595 = 0;
    shiftOut(dataArray[d]);
    shiftOut(dataArray[c]);
    shiftOut(dataArray[b]);
    shiftOut(dataArray[a]);
    STROBE_595 = 1;
    __delay_us(500);
}

char gps_tm_1[] = "GPGGA,";
char gps_tm_2[] = "GPRMC,";
char gstr[6];
int indx = 0;
int gps_flag = 0;
int a, b, c, d;
int led_state = 0;
int disp = 0;

void __interrupt() myISR() {
    if (RCIF == 1) {
        if (RCSTAbits.OERR) {
            CREN = 0;
            __delay_us(200);
            CREN = 1;
        }
        
        gpser(RCREG);
        RCIF = 0;
    }

}

void gpser(char data) {

    if (data > 0) {

        if (data == '$') {
            gps_flag = 1;
            indx = 0;
        } else if (gps_flag == 1) {
            if (indx < 6) {
                gstr[indx] = data;
                indx++;
            }
            if (indx == 6) {
                
                if (isEqualString(gstr,gps_tm_1)==0) {
                    gps_flag = 2;
                } else {
                    gps_flag = 0;
                }
                indx = 0;

            }
        } else if (gps_flag == 2) {
            if (indx < 6) {
                gstr[indx] = data;
                indx++;
            }
            if (indx >= 6) {
                a = gstr[0] - '0';
                b = gstr[1] - '0';
                c = gstr[2] - '0';
                d = gstr[3] - '0';

                gps_flag = 0;
                indx = 0;
                led_state++;
                led_state = led_state % 2;
                LED = led_state;
                printDisplay(a, b, c, d);

            }
            
        }

    }

}
int isEqualString(char c1[],char c2[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(c1[i]!=c2[i]){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void main(void) {
    system_init();
    dataArray[0] = 0x3F; //11111111
    dataArray[1] = 0x06; //11111110
    dataArray[2] = 0x5B; //11111100
    dataArray[3] = 0x4F; //11111000
    dataArray[4] = 0x66; //11110000
    dataArray[5] = 0x6D; //11100000
    dataArray[6] = 0x7D; //11000000
    dataArray[7] = 0x07; //10000000
    dataArray[8] = 0x7F; //00000000
    dataArray[9] = 0x6F; //11100000
    dataArray[10] = 0x80; //00000000

    while (1) {

    }
    return;
}

void system_init(void) {
    TRISB = 0x00;
    PORTB = 0X00; //Make all output of RB3 LOW

    TRISC = 0x80; // Configure Rx pin as input and Tx as output  
    TXSTA = 0x20; // Asynchronous mode, 8-bit data & enable transmitter
    RCSTA = 0x90; // 8-bit continous receive enable
    SPBRG = 31; // 9600 Baud rate at 20MHz
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1;

    INTCONbits.GIE = 1; // Enable all unmasked global INT
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // Enabel Peripheral interrupt
    PIR1bits.RCIF = 0; // Flag = 0 = no data in register
    PIE1bits.RCIE = 1; //enable rx to receive

}
```

Comment: In your procect works fine for a long time and then stops i guess it dont look like a software error.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  When you say that it stopped working, could you be more specific?

Comment: No, after development, the first night it was working fine. I kept it on the whole night. After a week, I tried again with the same code, and then it is not working. I checked with so many ways, now it feels like, no data is coming from RX pin, not a single time. Also I have verified circuit.